# PHP function returns unexpected values

Tags: php, arrays, function

Okay I'm new here and I have been trying to figure this out all day I have two functions one calling the other but my functions only returns the last value for example `29` when it should return multiple values. As wondering how can I fix this problem so that my functions return all the values.

Here is my PHP code.

```
function parent_comments(){
    if(articles_parent_comments_info($_GET['article_id']) !== false){
        foreach(articles_parent_comments_info($_GET['article_id']) as $comment_info){
            $comment_id = filternum($comment_info['comment_id']);
            reply_comment_count($comment_id);
        }
    }
}

function reply_comment_count($parent_id){
    if(articles_reply_comments_info($_GET['article_id']) !== false){
        foreach(articles_reply_comments_info($_GET['article_id']) as $reply_info){
            $comment_id = filternum($reply_info['comment_id']);
            $reply_id = filternum($reply_info['parent_id']);

            if($parent_id === $reply_id){
                reply_comment_count($comment_id);
            }   
        }
    }

    return $comment_id;
}
```

Comment: That code snippet doesn't show any expectation of an array. As written, nothing is done with the IDs. Can you edit to post some actual code? IE, what is `parent_comments()` doing? It outputs nothing and returns nothing. `reply_comment_count()` seems written oddly... it's recursive but does nothing to increase a counter.

Answer (score 0):

You use recursivity to return your `$comment_id`. If I understand your needs, you want to get every reply id linked to one article id.

In `reply_comment_count` you return `$comment_id` but as it rescursively used and you don't keep the previous id returned you only get the last.

If you want to get numerous `$comment_id` instead of only one, I suggest you to return an array where you push `$comment_id` every time you find one. Something like that:

```
func parent_comments(){
    loop in articles to get comment_id {
         count_array = reply_comment_count(comment_id, count_array)
    }
}

func reply_comment_count(parent_id, count_array) {
    loop to get id linked to parent_id {
        if id is an article {
           count_array = reply_comment_count(id, count_array) #recursive call
        }
        else {
          count_comment = count comment linked
          count_array.push(count_comment)
        }
    }
    return count_array # when you return your count_array due to recursive call it will be filled with every count, and not only the last
}
```

I hope this pseudo langage is clear for you. But as you only return the last count you found, you will only have this one.

Comment: This will probably be migrated to SO, where they'd prefer working code from pseudo code. If PHP is not your weapon of choice, I could translate the code for you.